# Is It correct way to create selctor of function If function contained uint values and struct as parameters in solidity

Tags: blockchain, solidity, web3js

function getMyFunctionSignature(
uint256 dbId,
launchpadLib.IDOInfo memory _idoInfo,
launchpadLib.IDOInfoTwo memory _IDOInfoTwo
) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
return (
abi.encodeWithSignature(
"createClone(uint256,(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint8,address,address),(uint64,uint64,address,uin64,bool,bool))",
dbId,
_idoInfo.tokenToBeSold,
_idoInfo.softcap,
_idoInfo.hardcap,
_idoInfo.minBuyLimit,
_idoInfo.maxBuyLimit,
_idoInfo.price,
_idoInfo.buyType,
_idoInfo.FounderAddress,
_idoInfo.tokenAddress,
_IDOInfoTwo.startTime,
_IDOInfoTwo.endTime,
_IDOInfoTwo.receiverAddress,
_IDOInfoTwo.VestingTime,
_IDOInfoTwo.isWhiteEnabled,
_IDOInfoTwo.isActive
)

```
    );
}
```

I just want to confirmed these is correct way to create slecotr of function in solidity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's correct:

Here another way:

```
contract MyContract {

  struct IDOInfo {
    uint256 tokenToBeSold;
    string tokenSymbol;
    uint256 tokenTotalSupply;
  }

  struct IDOInfoTwo {
    uint64 startTime;
    uint64 endTime;
    address receiverAddress;
    uint64 VestingTime;
    bool isWhiteEnabled;
    bool isActive;
  }

  function getMyFunctionSignature( uint256 dbId, IDOInfo memory _idoInfo, IDOInfoTwo memory _IDOInfoTwo ) public pure returns (bytes memory) {

    string memory functionSignature = "createClone(uint256,(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint8,address,address),(uint64,uint64,address,uin64,bool,bool))";

    bytes32 functionHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(functionSignature));

    bytes memory selector = new bytes(4);
    for (uint i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      selector[i] = byte(functionHash[i]);
    }

    return selector;
  }

}
```

Use like this :

```
contract MyContract {

  function getMyFunctionSignature() public view returns (bytes memory) {
    return getMyFunctionSignature(123456789, IDOInfo(1000, "ETH", 1000000), IDOInfoTwo(100, 200, address(0x1234567890), 1000000, true, false));   }

}
```

Comment: Okay great but .I want to create selcetor with values how we can do that ?